# What 7-zip command line syntax can I use to display errors only when creating a zip?

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I do not want all the file names being read to scroll in the command window, but would like only problem files to appear. Better yet, I would like to direct error output to a file. My only alternative at present is to display the created zip and compare a total file count to the original folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have been requesting Igor Pavlov for years now for a proper logging option but 7-Zip still lacks it. All you can do is redirect the output of the command line version (7za.exe) to a file yourself using `>Log.txt 2>&1` (or `>>` if you want to append to an existing file).

Additionally if you're calling it from a batch file you can test %ErrorLevel% for the following exit codes:

```
Code    Meaning
0       No error
1       Warning (Non fatal error(s)). For example, one or more files were locked by
        some other application, so they were not compressed.
2       Fatal error
7       Command line error
8       Not enough memory for operation
255     User stopped the process
```

Comment: I guess I can process the output and pick out errors.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of 7-zip, 15.06 beta, has a much better display in the command window. Files placed in the archive no longer scroll on screen and a nice concise summary is all that remains when the program finishes. This is exactly what I want. Everyone seems to be downloading the most recent beta version and there may no longer be a non-beta version.